# How do I add a UITtoolbar to my main view.nib?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitoolbar

How do I add using the InterfaceBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a UINavigationController, it's preferable to use its built-in toolbar.

In Interface Builder, check "Shows Toolbar" in your Navigation Controller's properties, and then use the `toolbarItems` attribute in your view controllers to populate the toolbar:

```
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a UINavigationController, you can drag a UIToolbar in from the library. I usually set its frame in the nib using the snap to guides feature. Then you can set the items with the method that @Can Berk Güder gives. Using `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` and/or `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` you can get a pretty good arrangement of buttons.

If you're doing it this way, just declare a `UIToolbar* toolbar` and set `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar* toolbar` in the interface of your view controller. In the implementation just `@synthesize toolbar;`. You can set the items in `viewDidLoad` and link the toolbar to your nib file by adding a new referencing outlet to 'toolbar' in File's Owner.